# Kivy add new vertex to rotation figure

Tags: python, 3d, rotation, kivy

I have some points(vertex) that rotate in 3d, but how can I add to this rotation vertex more points?
Example took wrom Kivy's monkey rotation example! I want when to click def on_touch_down and change coordinates of vertex , but nothing happends , how to reload **init** or mae be another way to do this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.graphics.opengl import *
from kivy.graphics import *
from objloader import ObjFile


class Renderer(Widget):
    a = [0.35, -0.41, -0.31, ----------->coord of vertex
      0.22, -0.41, 0.18,
     -0.50, -0.41, 0.18,
      0.35, 0.58, 0.68]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = RenderContext(compute_normal_mat=True)
        self.canvas.shader.source = resource_find('simple.glsl')
        super(Renderer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.cb = Callback(self.setup_gl_context)
            PushMatrix()
            self.setup_scene()
            PopMatrix()
            self.cb = Callback(self.reset_gl_context)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 1 / 60.)

    def setup_gl_context(self, *args):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def reset_gl_context(self, *args):
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def update_glsl(self, delta):
        asp = self.width / float(self.height)
        proj = Matrix().view_clip(-asp, asp, -1, 1, 1, 100, 1)
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = proj
        self.canvas['diffuse_light'] = (1.0, 1.0, 0.8)
        self.canvas['ambient_light'] = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
        self.rot.angle += delta * 20
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        Renderer.a=[0.3,0.3,0.3]   ----------------> here I change coord
        print (Renderer.a)
    def setup_scene(self):
        Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
        PushMatrix()
        Translate(0, 0, -3)
        self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)
        self.b =  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        UpdateNormalMatrix()
        self.mesh = Mesh(
             vertices=Renderer.a,    -------------->here use
             indices=self.b,
             fmt=[(b'v_pos', 3, 'float')],
             mode='points',
         )
        PopMatrix()


class RendererApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Renderer()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RendererApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets `Renderer.a`, but this doesn't do anything special. You need to instead change the `vertices` attribute of `self.mesh`, as this is the object representing the actual drawing on the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is no matter, I can add into self.mesh static list of verticies, nothing happens, I mean they are appeared but not rotation with verticies with in __init__ method!

Comment: I find solution, only by make kv file, in which: canvas: and canvas.after:PopMatrix(). But I must include kv files, wanted to not use it